# Export text data from Adobe Illustrator to MS Excel file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, export, microsoft-excel

I have finished a food brochure for a restaurant and now my client needs to have all food names and their prices in **MS Excel** file to modify names and prices in the future; whenever he needs. Copy text and paste into an **Excel** sheet is a time-wasting task and don't like to do it finally. Is there a free plugin or script to export text data from **Adobe Illustrator** to any **MS Excel** formats? (.***xlsx format***; would be better).

Comment: Unfortunately there's going to be some manual work involved, even with a plugin, since there's no way for the software to identify what text is which data type. You could export the text as a .TXT file to make it easier to manipulate into a format that excel can convert automatically though. Select all the text in illustrator and then go to file > export, and select the .TXT extension. Open that file in notepad or text edit and delete any unnecessary content. Use tabs and new lines to split stuff into rows and columns. Don't worry if it isn't aligned,excel will fix it.

Comment: Select all the cleaned up text and copy/paste it into Excel. The cell you paste it into will be the top-left cell of your table. When pasting, excel with automatically interpret the tabs and linebreaks as row and column boundaries, and divide the text into cells accordingly

Comment: I agree with you superluminal that we have to modify the exported text in Excel, even with a plugin or script. I created my list by copy/past for each item one by one and took time much. I didn't like to do it again in this way in the future. Also, I tried your suggestion for a piece of text as an example, but it didn't work for me as I expected, it needed much time to cut and paste data text from a cell to another one in MS Excel. I guess both methods take equal time to get a good result for me.